# Pandas conditional statement datetime

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have succesfully filtered my dataframe with this code:

```
df.set_index('Time')
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.between_time('08:00', '17:00')
```

Now, the df only contains the data in between the specified time frame. Now I want to count the values of the column "location", if this condition applies. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Doesn't `len(df)` give you what you want?  If you've filtered it, then you want the number of rows, right?  Or are there NaNs to ignore?

Comment: There are different locations (e.g. Paris, Berlin) so I need each one counted. If I apply value.counts it just counts without the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.between_time('08:00', '17:00')['location'].nunique()
```